# How to render ul li value dynamically from a sample json in angular 6

Tags: html, angular

I have a sample json,I need to create a sidebar using ul li tag and value comes from json.My json structure is something like this.
{"filter":{"Category1":{"value":["one","two","three"]},"Category2":{"value":["four","five","six"]}}}.I have already done in angularjs here http://plnkr.co/edit/D8M1U81tVz3UuzjWathk?p=preview , but This does not work in angular 6.Can anyone please help me,I am new in angular,Here is the code below

### app.html

```
<ul *ngFor="(x, y) of items.filter">
<li class="parent"><b>{{x}}</b></li>
<li class="child">
<ul>
<li *ngFor="p of y.value">{{p}}</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

### app.ts

```
export class Heroes {
  let items = {"filter":{"Category1":{"value":["one","two","three"]},"Category2":{"value":["four","five","six"]}}};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to work with an iterable objects when you try to use *ngFor in your html component.

So, that's my solution:

```
<ul *ngFor="let parent of (items.filter | keyvalue)">
  <li class="parent">{{ parent.key }}</li>
  <ul *ngFor="let child of (parent.value.value | keyvalue)">
    <li class="child">{{ child.value }}</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

First of all I used the keyvalue pipe from angular (https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) after that you are allowed to iterate your json object as you want without change it.

Also, here I leave an example of how it works (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqaaet)

Comment: Thanks for your help,I am getting this error "the pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found.." I have already updated the angular pipe version,can you please tell me how to fix this error.

Comment: The KeyValue Pipe is available in angular 6.1. If you can,  just update your dependencies and it will work. Srry for the mistake and hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the json format.

```
items = {"filter":
  [{
    "name":"Category1",
    "value":["one","two","three"]
  },
    {
    "name":"Category2",
    "value":["four","five","six"]
  }
  ]};
```

HTML

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items.filter">
  <li class="parent"><b>{{item.name}}</b></li>
  <li class="child">
   <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let p of item.value">{{p}}</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

The above code would work. *ngFor works with the [iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), the json format you've added has map(filter) of map(category) of map(value) format, where the values are not obtained to be iterated.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But Its not possible to change json format